# How to calculate the intеgral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate this definite integral:
$$\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{5\pi}{6}\sqrt{(\sin(t)\cos(t))^2}\,dt$$
I can`t uncover this root, because of interval of x.
Then what should I do? Help please.

Comment: One may recall that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\left|\sin(2t)\right|\,dt=\frac{1}{4}\int_{\pi/3}^{5\pi/3}\left|\sin\theta\right|d\theta $$ is not that difficult to compute.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{5\pi}{6}\sqrt{(\sin(t)\cos(t))^2}\,dt= \int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{5\pi}{6}|\sin(2t)|/2\,dt= {1\over 4}\int_\frac{\pi}{3}^\frac{5\pi}{3}|\sin(x)|\,dx= {1\over 4}\int_\frac{\pi}{3}^\frac{5\pi}{3}\sin(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Additivity of  the integral w.r.t. intervals (a.k.a. *Chasles' relation*) is your friend.